# HTML parser to a website chart

Tags: php, html, web

So, there is this website where they have some statistics about that website, and it's updated daily. What I want to do is to scrap that website and retrieve those informations to my website and put them into a line chart. Something like these http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart
or these http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#image_line_chart
The only problem is that I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I'm trying to use google charts to get content from the web and update it automatically, but what I can find is just to update it manually.

Comment: I think this is getting downvoted because it's a fairly vague question. You might want to edit this post and include info like operating system, web server, where you want to collect the data to (IE db, files, etc) and what you've tried (IE perl, batch file, cron job, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Get Permission

If you need to crawl a remote page, you should start by making sure you're not doing anything illegal. I'm in no way capable of counseling you about the legality of what you're looking to do, but I can say with assurance that some people don't like having their data scrapped - you really should check with the site administrators to see if they have any problem with this.

#### Got Permission? Good...

When you're cleared, consider using the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class to create a representation of the DOM in a series of nested objects that you can interact with pretty trivially:

```php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents("http://foo.com/data/statistics"));
```

If you're at all familiar with DOM-traversal and selection methods in JavaScript, the `DOMDocument` interface will seem pretty familiar. In order to get a particular element by ID, you'd use the appropriate method:

```php
$statistics = $doc->getElementById("statistics");
```

And to get all `TD` elements within *that* element:

```php
$cells = $statistics->getElementsByTagName("td");
```

Without going into too much detail, you could continue to use the methods provided to you by the `DOMDocument` class to traverse and select data. When you get to the actual nodes you're seeking, you could easily save their values into an array, and then output that array as a string with some JavaScript to show the Google graph.

#### Be Nice!

It would be wise to cache the results of this operation so that you don't hit the remote server every time the script runs. Save the output to a local file with a timestamp, and check that timestamp for expiration - when it's expired, remove it, and create a new cached result in its place.

#### What This Might Look Like

Here is a very basic implementation of what your solution may resemble when it is complete. Note that we only hit the remote server at most *once per day*.

```php
// Silence errors due to malformed HTML
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

// This function builds out data out, when necessary
function build_output () {
    // Create a DOMDocument, grab debt-clock HTML
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents("http://brillig.com/debt_clock/"));

    // Find element representing total National Debt
    $total = $doc->getElementsByTagName("img")->item(0);
    // Grab value from the alt attribute
    $total = $total->attributes->getNamedItem("alt")->nodeValue;
    // Second paragraph has two more values of interest
    $parag = $doc->getElementsByTagName("p")->item(1);

    // Build out resulting array of data: Natl. Debt, Population, Ind. Debt
    $data = Array(
        "ntl" => str_replace(" ", "", $total),
        "pop" => $parag->getElementsByTagName("b")->item(0)->nodeValue,
        "pay" => $parag->getElementsByTagName("b")->item(1)->nodeValue
    );

    // Return a JSON string of this data
    return json_encode($data);
}

// Most recent cache file (today)
$cache_name = date("Y-m-d");

if (!file_exists($cache_name)) {
    // Today's cache doesn't exist, create it.
    $output = build_output();
    $message = "Fresh: " . $output;
    file_put_contents($cache_name, $output);
} else {
    // Today has already been cached, load it.
    $message = "Cached: " . file_get_contents($cache_name);
}

// Show the user the output
echo $message;
```

When loading from cache, the output from the above script looks similar to this:

```
Cached: {
    "ntl":"$16,293,644,693,599.87",
    "pop":"313,929,808",
    "pay":"$51,902.19"
}
```

You can load that JSON data into any service you like now to generate an image representing its data.

Comment: I've found some information about retrieving information from the web. Google charts accept data from a .json file (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example), so what I need to know now is if it's possible to update the .json file automatically and how. Thanks.

Comment: @SandroMilhano I've update the answer to show how you can collect, and display the JSON data.

Comment: Thank you, I've found that very useful. But my question right now is how do i implement that? Do I create a new PHP file and paste the code or what? (Sorry, I'm pretty new in this stuff. I'm trying to learn.)

Comment: @SandroMilhano Yes, you would place this within a `.php` file. It will create a cache file in the same directory. You'll need to have a server running in order for this script to be able to run as well. If you found my answer helpful, upvote it. If it answers your question, consider accepting it. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I have placed it in a .php file and the only thing that it does is showing the code, it's not creating or doing anything. You can check the file here http://livept.net76.net/stats.php I made that website for testing this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @SandroMilhano Be sure to place at the start of the file an opening PHP tag.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I have a few questions that I would like you to answer if you can. Do I have to check the .php everyday in order for it to update, or will it update automatically, or will I have to use Cron Jobs. I want to make a chart for the last 30 days, so I don't think that creating an individual file is going to work, I would like to know how I can make the code to add the last day into the cache and delete the oldest in order to keep it at 30 entries. Thank you again.

Comment: @SandroMilhano As written you will need to manually run this script daily. You could setup a task on your machine to do this for you though. With regards to tracking 30 days, you could track these day-by-day and load in 30 days worth, or you could make a few slight modifications to load up the reports for the month, or the last 30 given days.